# Button onClick in viewPager?

Tags: android, button, android-viewpager, buttonclick

I've got a viewPager, and in second page i've got a button. I want it to do something onClick but it's not doing.

I've done on xml file:
android:onClick="buttonClick"

And also i've tried setOnClickListener both inside and outside of onCreat...

Neither of these worked out...

My viewPagerAdapter works fine! I can see pages, and switch between them. But I'm just not able to make a button do anything. It can be done in adapter, but i'll do lots of things so it's not gonna be useful...

Any help is appreciated.

Here's code:

```
public class ViewPagerProjectActivity extends Activity {

Button btn;
AbsoluteLayout l;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( this );
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById( R.id.viewpager );
    pager.setAdapter( adapter );
    pager.setCurrentItem(0);        

}   

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    l = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
    btn = (Button) l.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    // btn.setOnClickListener(this);        
}

public void buttonClick(View v) {
    if(v.equals(btn)) {                 
        l.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few problems with your code:

1. You should not be doing anything in `onSaveInstanceState` aside from...saving state. `onSaveInstanceState` is only called when the activity is about to be paused; it will not be called until then, therefore attaching a listener in there will not do anything. :(
2. You can't do `btn.setOnClickListener(this)` unless your `ViewPagerProjectActivity` implements onClickListener. So you could implement that, or just use the code below.

Move this code into `onCreate` after `setContentView(R.layout.main)`:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background));
}};
if (btn != null)
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: You're right... I made a mistake, it should be "onWindowFocusChanged" not "onSaveInstanceState"... Now it works :) By the way, it crashed as well with the way u said...